# Trouble changing boolean value of custom class using toggle SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, binding, toggle

I have a custom "Homework" class that has an "isComplete" boolean value. It is displayed on a custom view called HomeworkView.

HomeworkView has a subview called ToggleView which contains a label and toggle to show, you guessed it, whether the homework is complete or not. I am not sure how to set this up to where the toggle in ToggleView changes the value of the "homework" instance. Any help for this noob is appreciated.

My class:-

```
class Homework {
    var title: String
    var details: String
    var isComplete: Bool
        
    init(title: String, details: String, isComplete: Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.details = details
        self.isComplete = isComplete
    }
}
```

ToggleView and HomeworkView:-

```
struct ToggleView: View {
    @State var isComplete: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Is it complete?")
                .labelsHidden()
            
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(isComplete ? "YES" : "NO")
                    .foregroundColor(isComplete ? .green : .orange)
                
                Toggle("", isOn: $isComplete)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .frame(width: 80)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct HomeworkView: View {
    @State var homework: Homework
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(homework.isComplete ? "COMPLETED" : "PENDING")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            ToggleView(isComplete: homework.isComplete)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("\(homework.isComplete.hashValue)")
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@State` only works on `struct`s, so first, change `Homework` to a `struct`.

```
struct Homework {
    var title: String
    var details: String
    var isComplete: Bool
        
    /// no need for `init`, because structs get it for free!
}
```

Then, inside `HomeworkView`, you'll need to instantiate `homework` (`@State` vars usually need to be instantiated at the beginning).

```
@State var homework = Homework(title: "", details: "", isComplete: false)
```

Finally, change `ToggleView`'s `isComplete` to a `@Binding`.

```
struct ToggleView: View {
    @Binding var isComplete: Bool

    ...
}
```

`@Binding` makes the `Bool` value sync with the `@State`.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks, aheze!